# How do you get a c function pointer from a bridged function?

Tags: objective-c, swift

I'm trying to set up an event tap in swift using `CGEventTapCreate(...)`.  This takes a `CGEventTapCallback` function pointer as one of its arguments.

As far as I'm aware, there's no way to pass a swift function as a c function pointer in the current beta.

---

What I did instead was write the callback in Objective C, as usual:

```
// callback.h

CGEventRef callback(CGEventTapProxy proxy, CGEventType type, CGEventRef event,
        void *refcon);

// callback.m

CGEventRef callback(CGEventTapProxy proxy, CGEventType type, CGEventRef event,
        void *refcon)
{
    return NULL;
}
```

and then add the import to my bridging header:

```
// project-Bridging-Header.h

#import "callback.h"
```

---

This correctly exposes the function to swift.  However, it does so by converting the type of the function to a swift func.

As a result, I still can't provide it as an argument to `CGEventTapCreate(...)`

**Is there an inbuilt function which will transform a bridged function to a function pointer?**

Comment: Provide in CGEventTapCreate swift's block, where you call yours callback.

Comment: @Cy-4AH - I don't believe `CGEventTapCreate` exposes a block param, but I'm happy to be proven wrong in an answer!

Comment: Things got better in Swift 2, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31891002/how-do-you-use-cgeventtapcreate-in-swift

Answer (score 1):

I'm adding a workaround here, but I don't like it.

Basically, you just expose a function pointer directly:

```
// callback.h

CGEventRef callback(CGEventTapProxy proxy, CGEventType type, CGEventRef event,
        void *refcon);
extern CGEventTapCallBack callback_ptr;

// callback.m

#import callback.h

CGEventTapCallBack callback_ptr = callback;

CGEventRef callback(CGEventTapProxy proxy, CGEventType type, CGEventRef event,
        void *refcon)
{
    return NULL;
}
```