# How do you use CGEventTapCreate in Swift?

Tags: swift, macos, core-graphics, cgeventtap

Has anyone managed to get this function to work in Swift?

Here is a reference SO post from last year: [Using CGEventTapCreate Trouble with parameters in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26673329/using-cgeventtapcreate-trouble-with-parameters-in-swift)

Apple Doc: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/QuartzEventServicesRef/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGEventTapCreate

Here is how the CGEventTapCallBack is defined:

```
typealias CGEventTapCallBack = CFunctionPointer<((CGEventTapProxy, CGEventType, CGEvent!, UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) -> Unmanaged<CGEvent>!)>
```

Here is how I've written the block:

```
let eventTapCallBackBlock : @objc_block
(CGEventTapProxy, CGEventType, CGEventRef, UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) -> CGEventRef =
{ (eventTapProxy: CGEventTapProxy, eventType: CGEventType, event: CGEventRef, refcon: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) in
  return event
}
```

Then I've called CGEventTapCreate with the callback parameter like `unsafeBitCast(eventTapCallBackBlock, CGEventTapCallBack.self)`

I get a valid `CFMachPortRef` back, but at run time I get an access violation exception on first event. It would "seem" I'm close to a solution in swift in its current release state.

Using Xcode Version 6.4

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The `callback` parameter of `CGEventTapCreate()` is a C function pointer,
and in **Swift 1.x** it is not possible call it with a Swift function argument.

However, in **Swift 2** (Xcode 7), C functions that take function pointer arguments
can be called using closures or global functions (with the restriction that the
closure must not capture any of its local context).

As an example, here is a complete translation of
[Receiving, Filtering, and Modifying Key Presses and Releases](https://web.archive.org/web/20200503003001/http://osxbook.com/book/bonus/chapter2/alterkeys/)
to **Swift 3.**

```
import Foundation
import CoreGraphics

func myCGEventCallback(proxy: CGEventTapProxy, type: CGEventType, event: CGEvent, refcon: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) -> Unmanaged<CGEvent>? {
    
    if [.keyDown , .keyUp].contains(type) {
        var keyCode = event.getIntegerValueField(.keyboardEventKeycode)
        if keyCode == 0 {
            keyCode = 6
        } else if keyCode == 6 {
            keyCode = 0
        }
        event.setIntegerValueField(.keyboardEventKeycode, value: keyCode)
    }
    return Unmanaged.passUnretained(event)
}

let eventMask = (1 << CGEventType.keyDown.rawValue) | (1 << CGEventType.keyUp.rawValue)
guard let eventTap = CGEvent.tapCreate(tap: .cgSessionEventTap,
                                      place: .headInsertEventTap,
                                      options: .defaultTap,
                                      eventsOfInterest: CGEventMask(eventMask),
                                      callback: myCGEventCallback,
                                      userInfo: nil) else {
                                        print("failed to create event tap")
                                        exit(1)
}

let runLoopSource = CFMachPortCreateRunLoopSource(kCFAllocatorDefault, eventTap, 0)
CFRunLoopAddSource(CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), runLoopSource, .commonModes)
CGEvent.tapEnable(tap: eventTap, enable: true)
CFRunLoopRun()
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Have had any experience with @objc_blocks to solve this situation?

Comment: @jacobsd: CGEventTapCreate() takes a C function pointer as a parameter, not an Objective-C block. I don't think that you can solve that with a Swift 1.2 (Xcode 6.4) callback.

Comment: Holy Heck, that's uglier than the C/Objective-C versions... sigh... at least it's *possible*

Comment: Thanks for updating it for Swift 2!

Comment: Any idea on how to pass a value for the refcon parameter?  You're example is passing nil, and I haven't had any luck trying to find a way to pass in a value for a Swift type that I can then unwrap in the callback function and call a method on (e.g. a delegate object).

Comment: @chinabuffet: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33294620/how-to-cast-self-to-unsafemutablepointervoid-type-in-swift. The same technique should work here as well.

Comment: Ah dang, I had it pretty close at one point, just wasn't taking it back from the UnsafePointer to the original Type quite right... thanks!

Comment: It may be worth pointing out (since it took me a few minutes to work out what the issue was) that the function callback must be an actual func, not a class method.

Comment: @JamesWaldrop: Yes, the callback cannot be a instance or class method. I *can* be a closure (which captures no context). I'll update the answer later to make that more clear. Thank you for the feedback!

Comment: Any good reason to check `if [.keyDown , .keyUp].contains(type)` when `eventMask = (1 << CGEventType.keyDown.rawValue) | (1 << CGEventType.keyUp.rawValue)` ?

Comment: @aristidesfl: Good question. I adopted that from the linked-to C code.

Comment: @MartinR do you want to take a shot at this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17773225/cgeventpost-hold-a-key-shift

Comment: This stopped working for me since macOS 12.6. No exceptions, but the callback doesn't get called anymore. Any idea of what the problem could be? Thanks!

Comment: @aristidesfl: I have just tested it on my MacBook Air M2 with macOS 12.6, and it works as expected.

Comment: This solution leaks memory: `Unmanaged.passRetained` should be `Unmanaged.passUnretained`. I verified this by copying the solution into a new project and monitoring the memory in Activity Monitor while I typed as well as by profiling in Instruments on my own app.

Why? I don't fully understand it but `passRetained` leaves the refcount at +1 which means either we will call ARC's release on it or the calling code will call ARC's release on it. We don't release it and I'm guessing the calling API doesn't use ARC and thus never calls release, causing a leak.

Comment: @mcomella: You are right, I can confirm your observations. It seems that I misinterpreted the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgeventtapcallback?language) (“After the new event has been passed back to the event system, the new event will be released along with the original event.”) which made me think that the returned event must be +1 retained. Anyway, thanks for the notice, I have updated the code accordingly.

Comment: Since a recent MacOS update, probably 12.6.3, only the .listenOnly option can be used (not .defaultTap). Otherwise tapCreate returns nil, even when debugging the process as root in xcode. Also the callback is never called.

Comment: @Rip: It still works for me (on macOS 13) if you acquire the privilege to use the accessibility functions, e.g. using the code here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52160006/1187415. It also works if the process is running as root