# How to cast self to UnsafeMutablePointer<Void> type in swift

Tags: swift, pointers, casting, unsafe-pointers

Trying to pass "self" to a C function in swift, when calling following code:

```swift
var callbackStruct : AURenderCallbackStruct = 
    AURenderCallbackStruct.init(
      inputProc: recordingCallback,
      inputProcRefCon: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>
    )
```

What is the ideal way to cast "self" to a UnsafeMutablePointer type here?

Comment: How are you assigning self to inputProcRefCon?  Hope you have gone through this- https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html

Comment: Another example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33260808/swift-proper-use-of-cfnotificationcenteraddobserver-w-callback/33262376#33262376.

Comment: Actually @MartinR I think your answer here is more helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30788165/341994

Comment: @matt: But that is exactly the thread that I used as a "duplicate". I added another link in a comment because it shows a complete self-contained example, even if the question is different. – Perhaps I did not get what you meant?

Comment: Got it. Cheers guys.

Comment: @MartinR Right, I was just saying that the comment-link example is likely to confuse the OP more than help. Your duplicate-link example code is simple, clear, and direct. - And I have no idea what it does or why we have to jump through these elaborate hoops just in order to talk to C! :)

Comment: @MartinR it seems to me that this is what `withUnsafeMutablePointer` is for, and I've added an answer that demonstrates. If I'm wrong, please tell me and I'll delete it. But I just can't believe that you have jump through these Unmanaged and Opaque hoops just to do this.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

An object pointer (i.e. an instance of a *reference type*) can be
converted to a `UnsafePointer<Void>` (the Swift mapping of `const void *`, `UnsafeRawPointer` in Swift 3) and back. In Objective-C you would write

```
void *voidPtr = (__bridge void*)self;
// 
MyType *mySelf = (__bridge MyType *)voidPtr;
```

(See [3.2.4 Bridged casts](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#bridged-casts) in the Clang ARC documentation for the precise meaning of these
casts.)

Swift has an `Unmanaged` type for that purpose.
It is a bit cumbersome to use because it works with `COpaquePointer`
instead of `UnsafePointer<Void>`. Here are two helper methods
(named after the Objective-C `__bridge` cast):

```
func bridge<T : AnyObject>(obj : T) -> UnsafePointer<Void> {
    return UnsafePointer(Unmanaged.passUnretained(obj).toOpaque())
    // return unsafeAddressOf(obj) // ***
}

func bridge<T : AnyObject>(ptr : UnsafePointer<Void>) -> T {
    return Unmanaged<T>.fromOpaque(COpaquePointer(ptr)).takeUnretainedValue()
    // return unsafeBitCast(ptr, T.self) // ***
}
```

The "complicated" expression is only necessary to satisfy Swifts
strict type system. In the compiled code this is just a cast
between pointers. (It can be written shorter as indicated in the `***` comments
if you are willing to use "unsafe" methods, but the compiled
code is identical.)

Using this helper methods you can pass `self` to a C function as

```
 let voidPtr = bridge(self)
```

(or `UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>(bridge(self))` if the C function requires
a mutable pointer), and convert it back to an object pointer – e.g.
in a callback function – as

```
 let mySelf : MyType = bridge(voidPtr)
```

No transfer of ownership takes place, so you must ensure that `self`
exists as long as the void pointer is used.

---

And for the sake of completeness, the Swift equivalent of `__bridge_retained` and `__bridge_transfer` from Objective-C would be

```
func bridgeRetained<T : AnyObject>(obj : T) -> UnsafePointer<Void> {
    return UnsafePointer(Unmanaged.passRetained(obj).toOpaque())
}

func bridgeTransfer<T : AnyObject>(ptr : UnsafePointer<Void>) -> T {
    return Unmanaged<T>.fromOpaque(COpaquePointer(ptr)).takeRetainedValue()
}
```

`bridgeRetained()` casts the object pointer to a void pointer and
retains the object. `bridgeTransfer()` converts the
void pointer back to an object pointer and consumes the retain.

An advantage is that the object cannot be deallocated between the
calls because a strong reference is held. The disadvantage is that
the calls must be properly balanced, and that it can easily cause retain
cycles.

---

**Update for Swift 3 (Xcode 8):**

```
func bridge<T : AnyObject>(obj : T) -> UnsafeRawPointer {
    return UnsafeRawPointer(Unmanaged.passUnretained(obj).toOpaque())
}

func bridge<T : AnyObject>(ptr : UnsafeRawPointer) -> T {
    return Unmanaged<T>.fromOpaque(ptr).takeUnretainedValue()
}

func bridgeRetained<T : AnyObject>(obj : T) -> UnsafeRawPointer {
    return UnsafeRawPointer(Unmanaged.passRetained(obj).toOpaque())
}

func bridgeTransfer<T : AnyObject>(ptr : UnsafeRawPointer) -> T {
    return Unmanaged<T>.fromOpaque(ptr).takeRetainedValue()
}
```

The relevant changes to "unsafe pointers" are described in

- [SE-0017 Change Unmanaged to use UnsafePointer](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0017-convert-unmanaged-to-use-unsafepointer.md)
- [SE-0107 UnsafeRawPointer API](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0107-unsaferawpointer.md)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply and thanks for the effort. UnsafeMutablePointer(Unmanaged.passUnretained(self).toOpaque()) is the way to pass it. And nice to have those bridge methods to convert the pointer. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks!! Wasted so much time on this problem

Comment: Can this approach be used like this: 1. Pass in retained `Box` with `weak` variable to `self`. 2. Callback optionally bids the the value to strong. 3. If instance is deallocated and `Box` contains nil the callback consumes the retain of the `Box`?

Comment: @Kirsteins: That should be possible but you still have to unregister the callback if the instance is deallocated. It might be easier to pass  an unretained pointer and unregister the callback in the `deinit` method of the instance.

Comment: @matt: Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

It seems to me that this is what `withUnsafeMutablePointer` is for - to convert an arbitrary Swift pointer into a C pointer. So presumably you could do this (I have not tried it, but the code I've tested works safely):

```
var mself = self 
withUnsafeMutablePointer(&mself) { v in
    let v2 = UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>(v)
    myStruct.inputProcRefCon = v2
}
```

Comment: Note that there are going to be memory management issues; "unsafe mutable pointer" means that retaining what's at the far end of the pointer is up to _you_. Therefore I would think that `var mself = self` would need to be replaced by a persistent global.

Comment: This passes the address of `mself` to the C function, not the address of the object. As you said,  `mself` needs to be a global which I find quite inelegant. – The code from http://stackoverflow.com/a/30788165/341994 looks complicated, but actually does *nothing. It just casts the object pointer `self` to a mutable pointer. In fact it can be simplified to `let observer = unsafeAddressOf(self)`, the generated assembly code seems to be identical.

Comment: (Cont.)  The advantage of the explicit (complicated) expression is that it matches the reverse conversion from void pointer to object pointer, and that it can be modified to retain the object.

Comment: Actually the reverse conversion can be simplified as well using `unsafeBitCast()` ...

Comment: Where would you put the `mself` variable? A local variable does not work as you said. A global variable means that two separate instances of the class cannot be registered. An instance variable would lead to a retain cycle. – And how would you recover `self` from the pointer in the callback? I wasn't able to make it work with your approach. – Sorry to keep badgering you, but you reopened the question and asked for my opinion :) Since I cannot close it again, I have now added an answer which summarizes the conversion as I see it.

Comment: @MartinR You're not badgering me. I'm badgering you! My answer was intended to goad you into writing a real explanation, and that's exactly what you did. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

```
func bridge<T : AnyObject>(obj : T) -> UnsafePointer<Void> {
return UnsafePointer(Unmanaged.passUnretained(obj).toOpaque())
}


func bridge<T : AnyObject>(ptr : UnsafePointer<Void>) -> T {
return Unmanaged<T>.fromOpaque(ptr).takeUnretainedValue()
}

func bridgeRetained<T : AnyObject>(obj : T) -> UnsafePointer<Void> {
return UnsafePointer( Unmanaged.passRetained(obj).toOpaque())}

func bridgeTransfer<T : AnyObject>(ptr : UnsafePointer<Void>) -> T {
return Unmanaged<T>.fromOpaque(ptr).takeRetainedValue()}
```

Answer (score 0):

*This answer doesn't look as topic-specific for a callback as [Martin R's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33260808/swift-proper-use-of-cfnotificationcenteraddobserver-w-callback/33262376#33262376), but might be of use...*

You can typically pass a value of any type to an unsafe void pointer using the `&` operator:

```
func baz(p: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) -> String {
    return "\(p)"
}

var num = 5
print(baz(&num))
```

However, to pass `self` you'll need to do so in a context where `self` is mutable. That means you'll need to do this in a mutating method (or an `init`) of a value type, not a reference type:

```
struct FooValue {
    mutating func bar() {
        print(baz(&self))
    }
}

var myFooValue = FooValue()
myFooValue.bar()
```

If you want to use a reference type, you'll need to create a local copy of the reference and pass a pointer to that:

```
class FooReference {
    func bar() {
        var localSelf = self
        print(baz(&localSelf))
    }
}

let myFooReference = FooReference()
myFooReference.bar()
```