# Swift: Pass data to a closure that captures context

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I am trying to call a function when the internet connection is restored and the `updateOnConnection` variable is true. Here is my code:

```
func checkForConnection() {
    let host = "reddit.com"
    var context = SCNetworkReachabilityContext(version: 0, info: nil, retain: nil, release: nil, copyDescription: nil)
    let reachability = SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName(nil, host)!

    SCNetworkReachabilitySetCallback(reachability, { (_, flags, _) in
        if flags.rawValue == 0 { //internet is not connected

        } else { //internet became connected
            if self.updateOnConnection {
                self.refreshWallpaper()
            }
        }
    }, &context)

    SCNetworkReachabilityScheduleWithRunLoop(reachability, CFRunLoopGetMain(), kCFRunLoopCommonModes)
}
```

My problem is that the lines:

```
        if self.updateOnConnection {
            self.refreshWallpaper()
        }
```

cause the error: "`A C function pointer cannot be formed from a closure that captures context`"

I am not sure how to check the state of `updateOnConnection` and call `refreshWallpaper()` in the closure that monitors changes in the internet connection. How can I fix this, or is there a totally different workaround I should be using?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Similar as in [How to use instance method as callback for function which takes only func or literal closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33260808/swift-proper-use-of-cfnotificationcenteraddobserver-w-callback), you have to convert
`self` to a void pointer, store that in the context,
and convert it back to an object pointer in the closure:

```
func checkForConnection() {

    let host = "reddit.com"
    var context = SCNetworkReachabilityContext(version: 0, info: nil, retain: nil, release: nil, copyDescription: nil)
    context.info = UnsafeMutablePointer(Unmanaged.passUnretained(self).toOpaque())

    let reachability = SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName(nil, host)!

    SCNetworkReachabilitySetCallback(reachability, { (_, flags, info) in
        if flags.rawValue == 0 { //internet is not connected

        } else { //internet became connected
            let mySelf = Unmanaged<ViewController>.fromOpaque(COpaquePointer(info)).takeUnretainedValue()

            if mySelf.updateOnConnection {
                mySelf.refreshWallpaper()
            }
        }
        }, &context)

    SCNetworkReachabilityScheduleWithRunLoop(reachability, CFRunLoopGetMain(), kCFRunLoopCommonModes)
}
```

See also [How to cast self to UnsafeMutablePointer<Void> type in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33294620/how-to-cast-self-to-unsafemutablepointervoid-type-in-swift)
for more details about this mechanism.

*Remark:* `if flags.rawValue == 0` can be expressed slightly more
elegant as `if flags.isEmpty`, but what you *actually* should 
check is `if flags.contains(.Reachable)`.

---

**Update for Swift 3 (Xcode 8 beta 6):**

```
func checkForConnection() {

    let host = "reddit.com"
    var context = SCNetworkReachabilityContext(version: 0, info: nil, retain: nil, release: nil, copyDescription: nil)
    context.info = UnsafeMutableRawPointer(Unmanaged.passUnretained(self).toOpaque())

    let reachability = SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName(nil, host)!

    SCNetworkReachabilitySetCallback(reachability, { (_, flags, info) in
        if let info = info {
            if flags.rawValue == 0 { //internet is not connected

            } else { //internet became connected
                let mySelf = Unmanaged<ViewController>.fromOpaque(info).takeUnretainedValue()
                // ...
            }
        }
    }, &context)

    SCNetworkReachabilityScheduleWithRunLoop(reachability, CFRunLoopGetMain(), CFRunLoopMode.commonModes.rawValue)
}
```

Comment: I am getting this error for Swift 3 (in an Xcode 8 beta): "Value of type 'Unmanaged<MyClass>' has no member 'toOpaque'" in the line that is meant to assign to `context.info`. I.e. I cannot compile your code. Do you have an idea why this could be the case?

Comment: @Drux: There were some changes in the "unsafe pointer" APIs between the different Xcode 8 versions. I have now updated the code for the current Xcode 8 beta 6.

Comment: Thx! Amazing what substantial changes Swift syntax still undergoes.

Comment: if you use `passRetained()` shouldn't you use `takeRetainedValue()` as well? wouldn't `takeUnretainedValue` retain it again inside the closure causing a leak?

Comment: @BoteRock: It seems that I was not careful enough when translating the code from Swift 2 to Swift 3, thanks for letting me know.