# Closure Capture Context Swift

Tags: swift, callback, closures

I get this error when I try to change variables in the closure:

```
A C function pointer cannot be formed from a closure that captures context
```

Is there a work around or is it possible to still change the variables within the closure?

My Code:

```
let callback: @convention(c) (readStream: CFWriteStream!, event: CFStreamEventType, data: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) -> Void = {
    (readStream, event, data) -> Void in
    switch event {
    case CFStreamEventType.ErrorOccurred:
        self.isError = true
        break
    case CFStreamEventType.EndEncountered:
        self.isRunLoop = false
        break
    case CFStreamEventType.HasBytesAvailable:
        break
    case CFStreamEventType.OpenCompleted:
        break
    case CFStreamEventType.CanAcceptBytes:
        self.bytesWritten = CFWriteStreamWrite(readStream, self.buffer, self.leftOverSize)
        break
    default:
        break
    }
}

let registeredEvents: CFOptionFlags =
    CFStreamEventType.CanAcceptBytes.rawValue |
    CFStreamEventType.HasBytesAvailable.rawValue |
    CFStreamEventType.ErrorOccurred.rawValue |
    CFStreamEventType.EndEncountered.rawValue |
    CFStreamEventType.None.rawValue

var context = CFStreamClientContext(version: CFIndex(0), info: nil, retain: nil, release: nil, copyDescription: nil)
let stream = CFWriteStreamCreateWithFTPURL(nil, uploadURL).takeUnretainedValue()

CFWriteStreamSetClient(stream, registeredEvents, callback, &context)
```

Comment: The callback must be a global function or a closure which does not capture context. Similar issues: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33260808/swift-proper-use-of-cfnotificationcenteraddobserver-w-callback or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33551191/swift-pass-data-to-a-closure-that-captures-context.

Comment: How would i then know if there was an error?

Comment: You have to convert `self` to a void pointer, pass that as user data to the callback, and in the callback convert it back to an object pointer. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33294620/how-to-cast-self-to-unsafemutablepointervoid-type-in-swift.

Answer (score 7):

I assume you want to use this callback to pass it as the third argument (`clientCB`) to [CFWriteStreamSetClient](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFWriteStreamRef/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFWriteStreamSetClient).

Due to the fact that that parameter has the following type definition

```
typedef void (*CFWriteStreamClientCallBack) ( CFWriteStreamRef stream, CFStreamEventType eventType, void *clientCallBackInfo );
```

you can only use either a global function or a closure that doesn't capture any variables (like `self`) from the surrounding context.

What you can do in this case is to pass `self` to the `info` field of the `CFStreamClientContext` structure (the 4th parameter of `CFWriteStreamSetClient`), and use that info to reconstruct `self` within the closure:

```
let callback: @convention(c) (readStream: CFWriteStream!, event: CFStreamEventType, data: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) -> Void = {
    (readStream, event, data) -> Void in
    // assuming your class name is Client
    let client = unsafeBitCast(data.memory, Client.self)
    switch event {
    case CFStreamEventType.ErrorOccurred:
        client.isError = true
    case CFStreamEventType.EndEncountered:
        client.isRunLoop = false
    case CFStreamEventType.HasBytesAvailable:
        break
    case CFStreamEventType.OpenCompleted:
        break
    case CFStreamEventType.CanAcceptBytes:
        client.bytesWritten = CFWriteStreamWrite(readStream, client.buffer, client.leftOverSize)
    default:
        break
    }
}

var context = CFStreamClientContext(version: 0, info: unsafeBitCast(self, UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>.self), retain: nil, release: nil, copyDescription: nil)
CFWriteStreamSetClient(stream, 0, callback, &context)
```

Note. As with Objective-C, you need to make sure `self` is not destroyed before the stream is, otherwise you'll likely get into crashes if the stream receives new events.

Comment: I keep on getting this error: `Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11`.

Comment: At what line? How are you calling `CFWriteStreamSetClient`?

Comment: @HovyTech this seems to be a swift compiler issue, see [this radar](https://openradar.appspot.com/24541346). However you passed `nil` to the second argument for `CFStreamClientContext`, please see my updated answer of how the code should look like (assuming Apple fixes the compiler crash)