# How can I pass an anonymous method into a closure that captures context in Swift?

Tags: swift

I am trying to pass an anonymous function into a method that uses a closure. I have read [Swift: Pass data to a closure that captures context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33551191/swift-pass-data-to-a-closure-that-captures-context) and actually use its referenced question ([How to use instance method as callback for function which takes only func or literal closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33260808/how-to-use-instance-method-as-callback-for-function-which-takes-only-func-or-lit)) for part of the solution.

The problem is that these solutions are all working off of methods on a class.

This is the code I'm attempting to do:

```
func startListeningForEvents(onNameReceived: @escaping (String) -> Void) {
    selfPtr = Unmanaged.passRetained(self)

    self.tap = CGEvent.tapCreate(tap: CGEventTapLocation.cghidEventTap,
        place: CGEventTapPlacement.tailAppendEventTap,
        options: CGEventTapOptions.listenOnly,
        eventsOfInterest: CGEventMask(CGEventType.leftMouseUp.rawValue),
        callback: { proxy, type, event, refcon in
            let mySelf = Unmanaged<AccController>.fromOpaque(refcon!).takeUnretainedValue()
            let name = mySelf.onEventTap(proxy: proxy, type: type, event: event, refcon);

            // This is what I can't figure how to access
            onNameReceived(name);
            return nil;

        },
        userInfo: selfPtr.toOpaque());

}
```

In the above example. `onEventTap` is going to happen no matter who calls this class. I want the caller to choose what happens when a name is successfully grabbed. I get the error `A C function pointer cannot be formed from a closure that captures context`.

Comment: Is `onNameReceived` a method on the same class as `startListeningForEvents`? If so, you'd probably want to do `mySelf.onNameReceived(name)`

Comment: The error seems beautifully clear. C is not Swift. You are forming a C function. Therefore it cannot operate as a Swift closure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to pass an anonymous function into a method that uses a closure.

This is not precisely the case. `CGEvent.tapCreate` is a wrapper for the C function `CGEventTapCreate`, which takes a callback that is a C function. A C function is not a closure. A closure contains both code to execute and any values that it references. It is said to “close over” those values. A C function can't close over any values; it only has access to the arguments passed to it and to global variables.

To work around this behavior, a C API that takes a callback function usually also takes an opaque pointer (`void *` in C parlance) which you can use to pass in whatever extra state you want. In the case of `CGEvent.tapCreate`, that is the `userInfo` or `refcon` argument (the documentation refers to it by both names). You're passing `self` as that argument, but you actually want to pass in two values: `self` and `onNameReceived`.

One way to solve this is by adding a new instance property to hold `onNameReceived` for use by the callback, since you can access the instance property through the `self` reference you recover from `refcon`.

My preferred solution is to wrap the event tap in a class that lets you use a Swift closure as the handler.

```
class EventTapWrapper {
    typealias Handler = (CGEventTapProxy, CGEventType, CGEvent) -> ()

    init?(
        location: CGEventTapLocation, placement: CGEventTapPlacement,
        events: [CGEventType], handler: @escaping Handler)
    {
        self.handler = handler

        let mask = events.reduce(CGEventMask(0), { $0 | (1 << $1.rawValue) })

        let callback: CGEventTapCallBack = { (proxy, type, event, me) in
            let wrapper = Unmanaged<EventTapWrapper>.fromOpaque(me!).takeUnretainedValue()
            wrapper.handler(proxy, type, event)
            return nil
        }

        // I can't create the tap until self is fully initialized,
        // since I need to pass self to tapCreate.
        self.tap = nil

        guard let tap = CGEvent.tapCreate(
            tap: location, place: placement,
            options: .listenOnly, eventsOfInterest: mask,
            callback: callback,
            userInfo: Unmanaged.passUnretained(self).toOpaque())
            else { return nil }
        self.tap = tap
    }

    private let handler: Handler
    private var tap: CFMachPort?
}
```

With this wrapper, we can just use a regular Swift closure as the tap handler:

```
@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    func startListeningForEvents(onNameReceived: @escaping (String) -> Void) {
        self.tap = EventTapWrapper(
            location: .cghidEventTap, placement: .tailAppendEventTap,
            events: [.leftMouseUp],
            handler: { [weak self] (proxy, type, event) in
                guard let self = self else { return }
                onNameReceived(self.onEventTap(proxy: proxy, type: type, event: event))
        })
    }

    func onEventTap(proxy: CGEventTapProxy, type: CGEventType, event: CGEvent) -> String {
        return "hello"
    }

    private var tap: EventTapWrapper?
}
```

Please note that this is not a complete example (although it compiles). You also have to enable the tap (with `CGEvent.tapEnable`) and add it to a run loop (using `CFMachPortCreateRunLoopSource` and then `CFRunLoopAddSource`). You also need to remove the source from the run loop in the wrapper's `deinit`, lest it try to use the wrapper after the wrapper has been destroyed.

Comment: This answer made me realize a simpler answer, but marking yours as correct since it's closer to my original question.

Answer (score 0):

I marked Rob's answer as the one seeing as it better answers the original question. The solution I ended up using was this:

```
class MyClass {

  typealias MyFunctionDefinition = (String) -> Void
  private var onNameReceived: MyFunctionDefinition!
  init(callback: @escaping MyFunctionDefinition) {
    self.onNameReceived = callback;
  }

  // ... the code from my question above
        callback: { proxy, type, event, refcon in
            let mySelf = Unmanaged<AccController>.fromOpaque(refcon!).takeUnretainedValue()
            let name = mySelf.onEventTap(proxy: proxy, type: type, event: event, refcon);

            // This is what I can't figure how to access
            self.onNameReceived(name);
            return nil;

        },

}
```

I am able to just pass the callback in the constructor but I imagine other people might want to solve for the same thing in a way where it's done via a callback in the call.