# Converting an UnsafeMutablePointer to a [String:AnyObject]

Tags: swift, pointers, dictionary, casting

I have passed a `[String:AnyObject]` as userdata to addToolTipRect..

```
var myObject = [String:AnyObject]()

self.addToolTipRect( binCoordinates, owner: self, userData: &myObject )
```

So, in stringForToolTip, I need to convert it back to `[String:AnyObject]`

`var theData = [String:AnyObject](data)` does not work.

Comment: How do you pass the dictionary as userdata? Does this help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33294620/how-to-cast-self-to-unsafemutablepointervoid-type-in-swift?

Comment: Edited my question to provide those details.

Comment: The other question you pointed to leads to a compile error that T could not be inferred.

Comment: What is the signature of the function.

Comment: Is userData : UnsaveMutablePointer of type Void?

Comment: func addToolTipRect(_ aRect: NSRect,
              owner anObject: AnyObject,
           userData data: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) -> NSToolTipTag

Comment: func view(_ view: NSView,
stringForToolTip tag: NSToolTipTag,
           point point: NSPoint,
        userData data: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) -> String

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// userData: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>

let pUserData = UnsafeMutablePointer<Dictionary<String,AnyObject>>(userData)

// you can accsees all properties and functions via

pUserData.memory.myPropery // read or write myObject.myProperty
pUserData.memory.foo()     // execute myObject.foo()
```