# Swift: CFArray : get values as UTF Strings

Tags: string, swift, utf-8

I call some functions that return a `CFArray` of `CFStringRef` values. I need to get utf strings from them. As I didn't want to make my code too complicated, I did the following:

`let initString = "\(TISCreateInputSourceList(nil, false).takeUnretainedValue())"`

And then I just split the resulting string by `\n`s to get an array of Swift strings. However, when the function started returning non-ascii strings, trouble started. I started getting strings like "\U2345\U2344".

Then i tried to take the CFArray and iterate over it getting the values and possibly converting them to Strings, but I can't get the values from it:

`let ar = TISCreateInputSourceList(nil, true).takeUnretainedValue()
        for i in 0...CFArrayGetCount(ar) - 1 {
            print(">> ( CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(ar, i).memory )")
        }`

The values are always empty.

How can i get the actual values?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are some issues here. First, `TISCreateInputSourceList()`
has "Create" in its name which means that it returns a (+1) retained
object and you have to take the value with `takeRetainedValue()`,
not `takeUnretainedValue()`, otherwise the code will leak memory:

```
let srcs = TISCreateInputSourceList(nil, true).takeRetainedValue()
```

You could now use the `CFArray...` methods to get values from the array,
but it is much easier to convert it to a `NSArray` (which is "toll-free bridged"):

```
let srcs = TISCreateInputSourceList(nil, true).takeRetainedValue() as NSArray
```

This is not an array of `CFStringRef` values but an array of
`TISInputSource` objects. You can convert the `NSArray` to a Swift array:

```
let srcs = TISCreateInputSourceList(nil, true).takeRetainedValue()
                    as NSArray as! [TISInputSource]
```

The forced cast `as!` is acceptable here because the function is
*documented* to return an array of input sources.

Now you can simply iterate over the elements of the array:

```
for src in srcs  {
    // do something with `src` (which is a `TISInputSource`)
}
```

The properties of an input source are retrieved with the `TISGetInputSourceProperty()` function, for example:

```
let ptr = TISGetInputSourceProperty(src, kTISPropertyInputSourceID)
```

This returns a "void pointer" (`UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>`) which has to be converted to an object
pointer of the appropriate type (which is `CFStringRef` for the 
`kTISPropertyInputSourceID` property). Unfortunately, this is a bit
complicated (compare [How to cast self to UnsafeMutablePointer<Void> type in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33294620/how-to-cast-self-to-unsafemutablepointervoid-type-in-swift)):

```
let val = Unmanaged<CFString>.fromOpaque(COpaquePointer(ptr)).takeUnretainedValue()
```

Again we can take advantage of toll-free bridging, now from
`CFStringRef` to `NSString` and `String`:

```
let val = Unmanaged<CFString>.fromOpaque(COpaquePointer(ptr)).takeUnretainedValue()
                    as String
```

Putting it all together:

```
let srcs = TISCreateInputSourceList(nil, true).takeRetainedValue()
                as NSArray as! [TISInputSource]
for src in srcs  {
    let ptr = TISGetInputSourceProperty(src, kTISPropertyInputSourceID)
    let val = Unmanaged<CFString>.fromOpaque(COpaquePointer(ptr)).takeUnretainedValue()
                as String
    print(val)
}
```

Comment: @Noobie: No. `let srcs = TISCreate....takeRetainedValue()` "transfers the ownership", and the array will be released when `srcs` goes out of scope (since Swift uses ARC)