# How do I convert my swift class to an UnsafePointer like the __bridge in objective-c

Tags: c, swift, swift2, unsafe-pointers, secure-transport

I'm trying to implement a swift bridge to the [SecureTransport](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Reference/secureTransportRef/) C libraries. I 'think' I can pass in anything as the connection as long as I know how to read stuff from it in my sslReadCallback/sslWriteCallback implementations. This is the assumption I'm working with. This seems to be the case when I view the definition of SSLConnectionRef:

```
/* Opaque reference to an I/O connection (socket, endpoint, etc.) */
public typealias SSLConnectionRef = UnsafePointer<Void>
```

So I just need to turn my class into UnsafePointer. Unfortunately the compiler doesn't like my attempts. Can any one give me tips?

```
func startSSLProcess()
{
    self.sslContext = SSLCreateContext(kCFAllocatorDefault, SSLProtocolSide.ClientSide, SSLConnectionType.StreamType)
    if let sslContext = self.sslContext
    {
        SSLSetIOFuncs(sslContext, sslReadCallback, sslWriteCallback)
        SSLSetConnection(sslContext, UnsafePointer(self)) // <-- error
        SSLSetSessionOption(sslContext, SSLSessionOption.BreakOnClientAuth, true)
        SSLHandshake(sslContext)
    }
}
```

In GCDAsyncSocket, it does this:

```
status = SSLSetConnection(sslContext, (__bridge SSLConnectionRef)self);
```

and

```
SubZeroGCDAsyncSocket *asyncSocket = (__bridge SubZeroGCDAsyncSocket *)connection;
```

.. to unwrap. Whats the swift equivalent of this?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was here:

[How to cast self to UnsafeMutablePointer<Void> type in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33294620/how-to-cast-self-to-unsafemutablepointervoid-type-in-swift)

So now I do the following:

```
func startSSLProcess()
{
    self.sslContext = SSLCreateContext(kCFAllocatorDefault, SSLProtocolSide.ClientSide, SSLConnectionType.StreamType)
    if let sslContext = self.sslContext
    {
        SSLSetIOFuncs(sslContext, sslReadCallback, sslWriteCallback)
        SSLSetConnection(sslContext, UnsafePointer(Unmanaged.passUnretained(self).toOpaque()))
        SSLSetSessionOption(sslContext, SSLSessionOption.BreakOnClientAuth, true)
        SSLHandshake(sslContext)
    }
}
```

And I unwrap like this:

```
    let transportWrapper:SecureTransportWrapper = Unmanaged<SecureTransportWrapper>.fromOpaque(COpaquePointer(connection)).takeUnretainedValue()
```

Substitute your own type for SecureTransportWrapper.