# Swift's memory management

Tags: swift, memory, memory-management, swift3

I'm a little confused regarding Swift's memory management. Can someone explain to me how come kid1 always stays at the same memory address? Even when I do kid1=kid2 or initialize a new object?

[image: Sample Playground]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code prints the memory location of the `kid1` variable,
and that does not change if you assign a new value to the variable.

If `Kid` is a reference type (class) then you can use 
`ObjectIdentifier` to get a unique identifier for the class *instance*
that the variable references:

```
var kid1 = Kid(name: "A")
var kid2 = Kid(name: "B")

print(ObjectIdentifier(kid1)) // ObjectIdentifier(0x0000000100b06220)
print(ObjectIdentifier(kid2)) // ObjectIdentifier(0x0000000100b06250)

kid1 = kid2
print(ObjectIdentifier(kid1)) // ObjectIdentifier(0x0000000100b06250)
```

The object identifier happens to be the address of the pointed-to
instance, but that is an undocumented implementation detail.
If you need to convert an object reference to a real *pointer*
then you can do (compare [How to cast self to UnsafeMutablePointer<Void> type in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33294620/how-to-cast-self-to-unsafemutablepointervoid-type-in-swift))

```
print(Unmanaged.passUnretained(kid1).toOpaque())
```

Answer (score 0):

Why `kid1` is pointing to the same `MemoryAddress` each time?

In general, a class is a reference type. Which means, all instances of a class will share a single copy of data.
I.e, it's like a mutable data, if you change a data at any once instance of class, then it will affect that change to all its dependent instances.

It mainly deals with the memory addresses.

I think you have declared your class like below:

```
class Kid {
    var name: String?
    init(name:String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}
```

then for

1. `var kid1 = Kid(name: "A")`: For `kid1` instance it will assign some memory address, say  `<Kid: 0x60400024b400>`
2. `var kid2 = Kid(name: "B")`: For `kid2` instance it will assign some other memory address, say  `<Kid: 0x60400024b760>`
3. when you do `kid1 =kid2`: `kid1` memory address will get changed to `kid2` memory address. So, `kid1` and `kid2` will pointing to same memory address.
4. `kid1.name = "C"`: now if a change `kid1.name`,..it will reflect to `kid2.name` value also,because both are pointing to same memory address.

Therefore you get:

```
kid1.name == "C"
kid2.name == "C"
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 categories that are supported by Swift (Value Types, Reference Type). We have 3 different behaviours that we can have for those types - Copy by reference, Copy by value and Copy-on-Write. Classes as in your case are using copy by reference which means both instances point to same address - share a single copy of data. More details are described in my post about swift memory management and performance, I go as deep as binary values in the memory. I hope it helps:
[Swift Memory Management and Performance](https://dev.to/michalrogowski/memory-management-swift-266b)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/24187835)

Comment: @kenny_k I’ve added more context to my answer, I hope now it’s ok.