# MDQueryGetResultAtIndex and UnsafeRawPointer in Swift 3

Tags: swift, macos, spotlight

I'm having trouble exploring the results of a Spotlight search in Swift 3 using MDQuery. I expect `MDQueryGetResultAtIndex` to yield an MDItem, and in C/Objective-C, that assumption works, and I can call `MDItemCopyAttribute` on it to explore the item. Here, for example, I successfully get the pathname of a found item:

```
MDItemRef item = (MDItemRef)MDQueryGetResultAtIndex(q,i);
CFStringRef path = MDItemCopyAttribute(item,kMDItemPath);
```

But in Swift 3, `MDQueryGetResultAtIndex` returns an `UnsafeRawPointer!` (it's a pointer-to-void in C). To get past that, I've tried, for example:

```
if let item = MDQueryGetResultAtIndex(q, 0) {
    let ptr = item.bindMemory(to: MDItem.self, capacity: 1)
    let path = MDItemCopyAttribute(ptr.pointee, kMDItemPath)
}
```

but that crashes, and logging shows that `ptr.pointee` is an NSAtom. It is quite evident that my personal UnsafeRawPointer mojo is not working (and to be frank I've always found this confusing).

How would I transform this UnsafeRawPointer into something I can successfully call `MDItemCopyAttribute` on?

**Alternatives**

- I can get over this hump by putting my Objective-C code into an Objective-C helper object and calling it from Swift; but I'd like to write a pure Swift solution.
- Similarly, I could probably rewrite my code to use the higher-level NSMetadataQuery, and I may well do so; but my original Objective-C code using the lower-level MDQueryRef works fine, so now I'm curious how to turn it directly into Swift.

---

**Complete code** for those who would like to try this at home:

```
let s = "kMDItemDisplayName == \"test\"" // you probably have one somewhere
let q = MDQueryCreate(nil, s as CFString, nil, nil)
MDQueryExecute(q, CFOptionFlags(kMDQuerySynchronous.rawValue))
let ct = MDQueryGetResultCount(q)
if ct > 0 {
    if let item = MDQueryGetResultAtIndex(q, 0) {
        // ... 
    }
}
```

Comment: Dumb question, what about `item?.assumingMemoryBound(to: MDItem.self)?.pointee` to get the MDItem?

Comment: @JAL same result as `bindMemory`. I also tried using them together, just in case. :)

Comment: Ah ok, worth a shot.  My guess as to why you're getting the `NSAtom` is because your `ptr` is turning into `UnsafePointer(0x1)`, and getting the `pointee` of that is the equivalent of calling something like `(id)0x1` which is an `__NSAtom`.  I'll keep digging.

Comment: I would *assume* you have to go through `Unmanaged<MDItem>.fromOpaque(...)` – but I have no idea how `MDQuery` works, so cannot test it.

Comment: @Hamish I'll try it! I could also post more code, of course. Hang on a sec.

Comment: @Hamish, yep, you got it. I wrote `let realitem = Unmanaged<MDItem>.fromOpaque(item).takeUnretainedValue()` and badda-bing badda-boom. Go ahead and post an answer! Would you mind explaining _why_ this works and my code didn't? I've never understood this dance.

Comment: @Hamish: You are right (was about to write an answer when I saw your comment) . It is the same mechanism  as in http://stackoverflow.com/a/33310021/1187415: `let item = Unmanaged<MDItem>.fromOpaque(rawPtr).takeUnretainedValue()` – or  `let item = bridge(ptr: rawPtr) as MDItem` using the helper functions from that posting.

Comment: Ah @Hamish that's brilliant.  Is this because the function `MDQueryGetResultAtIndex` returns an `MDItemRef`, which is really an unmanaged CoreFoundation object that Swift is incorrectly bridging as an actual `MDItem` instance (instead of `Unmanaged<MDItem>`)?  Sounds like we should open a radar.

Comment: Yes, @MartinR, of course I remember that post of yours (it's the one I was only able to upvote once). But isn't binding memory _also_ a way of casting the pointer? Obviously not, in this case; but _why_ not?

Comment: @matt: You cast the pointer and then *dereference* it in `ptr.pointee`, which is the problem. In other words, you interpret the void pointer as a *pointer* to an `MDItemRef`

Comment: @MartinR I did that because when I logged `ptr` all I saw was a number, presumably the address.

Comment: @matt The problem is that you're trying to rebind the pointee's memory (i.e the underlying instance) to an `MDItem`, which is a reference type. So you're interpreting (part of) the underlying instance as a pointer to the instance.

Comment: @JAL Yes, it's brought into Swift as an opaque pointer to an Core Foundation object (i.e `void*`). I wouldn't say it's incorrectly bridged (apart from the type safety hole, there's nothing really wrong with giving you back an opaque pointer). From what I *understand* from the `MDQueryGetResultAtIndex` docs, it's possible to get back a custom object if you want through supplying a custom creation function – so I don't think it's possible for Swift to bridge it back directly as an `MDItem` (as it might not be).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem in your code

```
if let item = MDQueryGetResultAtIndex(q, 0) {
    let ptr = item.bindMemory(to: MDItem.self, capacity: 1)
    let path = MDItemCopyAttribute(ptr.pointee, kMDItemPath)
}
```

is that the `UnsafeRawPointer` is interpreted as a *pointer* to an
`MDItem` reference and then dereferenced in `ptr.pointee`, but
the raw pointer *is* the `MDItem` reference, so it is dereferenced
once too often.

The "shortest" method to convert the raw pointer to an `MDItem` reference
is `unsafeBitCast`:

```
let item = unsafeBitCast(rawPtr, to: MDItem.self)
```

which is the direct analogue of an (Objective-)C cast.
You can also use the [`Unmanaged`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/unmanaged) methods
to convert the raw pointer to an unmanaged reference and from there
to a managed reference (compare  [How to cast self to UnsafeMutablePointer<Void> type in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33294620/how-to-cast-self-to-unsafemutablepointervoid-type-in-swift/33310021#33310021)):

```
let item = Unmanaged<MDItem>.fromOpaque(rawPtr).takeUnretainedValue()
```

This looks a bit more complicated but perhaps expresses the intention 
more clearly. The latter approach works also with (+1) retained 
references (using `takeRetainedValue()`).

Self-contained example:

```
import CoreServices

let queryString = "kMDItemContentType = com.apple.application-bundle"
if let query = MDQueryCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, queryString as CFString, nil, nil) {
    MDQueryExecute(query, CFOptionFlags(kMDQuerySynchronous.rawValue))

    for i in 0..<MDQueryGetResultCount(query) {
        if let rawPtr = MDQueryGetResultAtIndex(query, i) {
            let item = Unmanaged<MDItem>.fromOpaque(rawPtr).takeUnretainedValue()
            if let path = MDItemCopyAttribute(item, kMDItemPath) as? String {
                print(path)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "that the UnsafeRawPointer is interpreted as a _pointer_ to an MDItem reference and then dereferenced in `ptr.pointee`, but the raw pointer _is_ the MDItem reference" And this is the key fact about when the `fromOpaque` dance is needed that I have never understood. As JAL implies in a comment above, the way a CFType gets bridged is what trips me up here.

Comment: Nice answer Martin and great question matt.  Sounds like this API is a perfect example of one that needs an update for Swift.

Comment: I think I see what @JAL is getting at here. The usual assumption behind a pointer-to-void / UnsafeRawPointer is that we've cast away the type of what's _at the far end_ of the pointer. But when a CFTypeRef is slotted in here, as Martin R says, it _is_ the pointer. That's what I've never appreciated until now.