# Assigning UnsafeMutablePointer value to UnsafePointer without unsafeBitCast

Tags: swift, pointers, swift3, casting, unsafe-pointers

I am working with a C API that defines a structure with const char* and a function that returns a char* and am trying to find the best way to do the assignment.

Is there a way to do this without using unsafeBitCast? If I don't put the cast then I get this error:

```
Cannot assign value of type 'UnsafeMutablePointer<pchar>' 
(aka 'UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>') 
to type 'UnsafePointer<pchar>!' 
(aka 'ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<UnsafePointer<UInt8>>')
```

Also, will the initialization of pairPtr below using pair() allocate a pair struct on the stack to initialize the allocated pair on the heap because this seems inefficient for the case where the structure just has to be zero'd out.

Here is sample code:

C library header (minimized to demonstrate the problem):

```
#ifndef __PAIR_INCLUDE__
#define __PAIR_INCLUDE__

typedef unsigned char pchar;

pchar*
pstrdup(const pchar* str);

typedef struct _pair {
    const pchar* left;
    const pchar* right;
} pair;

#endif // __PAIR_INCLUDE__
```

My Swift code:

```
import pair

let leftVal = pstrdup("left")
let rightVal = pstrdup("right")

let pairPtr = UnsafeMutablePointer<pair>.allocate(capacity: 1)
pairPtr.initialize(to: pair())

// Seems like there should be a better way to handle this:
pairPtr.pointee.left = unsafeBitCast(leftVal, to: UnsafePointer<pchar>.self)
pairPtr.pointee.right = unsafeBitCast(rightVal, to: UnsafePointer<pchar>.self)
```

The C code:

```
#include "pair.h"
#include <string.h>

pchar*
pstrdup(const pchar* str) {
    return strdup(str);
}
```

The module definition:

```
module pair [extern_c] {
    header "pair.h"
    export *
}
```

Comment: Why not simply `let p = pair(left: leftVal, right: rightVal)` ? I don't see why the unsafeBitCast should be needed, perhaps I am overlooking something?

Comment: That would work but for the real structure there are 20 attributes and I only assign values to about 5. Is there a simple way to assign directly without the cast?

Comment: If the only problem is the different mutability then `p.left = UnsafePointer(leftVal)` should work.

Comment: Yes you are right, can you please post that as an answer and I'll accept it. I had thought I'd tried that. By the way your answer to this question was also helpful for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33294620/how-to-cast-self-to-unsafemutablepointervoid-type-in-swift

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create an `UnsafePointer<T>` from an `UnsafeMutablePtr<T>`
simply with

```
let ptr = UnsafePointer(mptr)
```

using the

```
/// Creates an immutable typed pointer referencing the same memory as the
/// given mutable pointer.
///
/// - Parameter other: The pointer to convert.
public init(_ other: UnsafeMutablePointer<Pointee>)
```

initializer of `UnsafePointer`. In your case that would for example be

```
p.left = UnsafePointer(leftVal)
```