# UnsafeMutableRawPointer to UnsafeMutablePointer<T>: EXC_BAD_ACCESS on pointee

Tags: swift, pointers

I'm trying to get an `UnsafeMutablePointer` from an `UnsafeMutableRawPointer` obtained using `Unmanaged.passUnretained().toOpaque()`:

```
class C { var foo = 42, bar = "bar" }
let c = C()

let rawPointer = Unmanaged.passUnretained(c).toOpaque()

let pointer = rawPointer.bindMemory(to: C.self, capacity: 1)
let pointee = pointer.pointee
print(pointee.foo) // EXC_BAD_ACCESS
```

Here's some LLDB output, which looks strange to me as everything seems alright in `pointer` until I ask for its `pointee`:

```
(lldb) frame variable -L c
scalar: (memtest2.C) c = 0x0000000101d00030 {
0x0000000101d00040:   foo = 42
0x0000000101d00048:   bar = "bar"
}
(lldb) frame variable -L rawPointer
0x00000001005e2e08: (UnsafeMutableRawPointer) rawPointer = {
scalar:   _rawValue = 0x0000000101d00030 {
0x0000000101d00040:     foo = 42
0x0000000101d00048:     bar = "bar"
  }
}
(lldb) frame variable -L pointer
0x00000001005e2e10: (UnsafeMutablePointer<memtest2.C>) pointer = 0x0000000101d00030
(lldb) frame variable -L pointer._rawValue
scalar: (memtest2.C) pointer._rawValue = 0x0000000101d00030 {
0x0000000101d00040:   foo = 42
0x0000000101d00048:   bar = "bar"
}
(lldb) frame variable -L pointee
0x00000001005e2e18: (memtest2.C) pointee = 0x00000001005b65d8 {
0x00000001005b65e8:   foo = 140736790071664
0x00000001005b65f0:   bar = ""
}
```

I've also tried `assumingMemoryBound(to:)`, `load(as:)`, or simply:

```
let pointer = UnsafePointer<C>(bitPattern: Int(bitPattern: rawPointer))!
print(pointer.pointee.foo) // EXC_BAD_ACCESS
```

But I always get this EXC_BAD_ACCESS error. What is going on here?

Comment: Try `let obj = Unmanaged<C>.fromOpaque(rawPointer).takeUnretainedValue();print(obj.foo)` .

Comment: @OOPer My end-goal is not to access the `C` instance but really to obtain a valid typed pointer from the raw one.

Comment: Then I cannot understand your _end-goal_. Anyway, your code only works when `rawPointer` is a pointer to a reference to an instance of `C`, `Unmanaged.passUnretained(c).toOpaque()` does not make it.

Comment: `let obj = Unmanaged<C>.fromOpaque(rawPointer).takeUnretainedValue()` *is* a valid typed pointer to the C instance, and is the correct answer to your question. Compare https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33294620/how-to-cast-self-to-unsafemutablepointervoid-type-in-swift.

Comment: @MartinR `takeUnretainedValue()` returns the `c` instance when I would like to get a `Unsafe[Mutable]Pointer<C>` instance (from the `UnsafeMutableRawPointer`).

Comment: @nyg: Your `c` variable is already a pointer to a `C` instance (because classes are reference types). And `obj` will also be a pointer to a `C`  instance.

Comment: @MartinR So you mean that `c` (and not an instance of `UnsafeMutablePointer<C>`) is the typed version of an `UnsafeMutableRawPointer`? I can understand this but it would seem quite strange to me. Can't I have then a pointer on that pointer? Such as `pointer.pointee == c`?

Comment: If you declare `c` as a *variable* then `withUnsafeMutablePointer(to: &c)` gives you a pointer to that variable. That would allow you to modify that variable. Is that really what you want?

Comment: @nyg: Perhaps you can provide more information what the pointer is needed for (some concrete code).

Comment: @MartinR I was trying to do something like this: https://pastebin.com/1tGhYAsG. I guess I should rather not have that pointer property, I'd be better off storing the value for stringValue and intValue directly in the init... In my case, using withUnsafeMutablePointer would not be useful because a) the created pointer shouldn't be used outside the closure (says doc) and b) it doesn't show the address where the c instance is located.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155181/discussion-between-martin-r-and-nyg).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My `rawPointer` points to where the `c` instance data is located. It is not, as I expected, a pointer on the reference. Classes are reference types: the value of `c` is the memory address of where the class instance data is located. Yet the `toOpaque()` doc was clear:

> Unsafely converts an unmanaged class reference to a pointer.

(`toOpaque()` actually calls `unsafeBitCast(c, UnsafeMutableRawPointer.self)`)

To have a pointer on the reference one can simply do:

```
let referencePointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<C>(&c)
```

As my `rawPointer` points to the instance data, doing `pointer.pointee` tells the runtime that the first word of the instance data is a (or its) reference. Which of course isn't true nor makes sense.

Illustrating: (I've slightly change my initial code: both `foo` and `bar` are Int)

```
(lldb) frame variable c
(testmem.C) c = 0x0000000101833580 (foo = 42, bar = 84)
```

This (`0x0000000101833580`) is where the instance data is located. Let's see what the memory contains at this address:

```
(lldb) memory read 0x0000000101833580
0x101833580: e0 65 5b 00 01 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0x101833590: 2a 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 54 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

I learned that the first word (`e0 65 5b 00 01 00 00 00`) is type data, the second (`02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00`) is reference counts (I don't know more about this), and the rest is the instance data. Indeed, `0x2a` is 42 and `0x54` is 84. The value of `foo` and `bar`.

Doing `pointer.pointee` means telling the runtime that the first word (`e0 65 5b 00 01 00 00 00` or `0x00000001005b65e0`) is a reference pointing to where our instance data is located (which is obviously not the case)! Implying that `pointer.pointee.foo` is located at `0x00000001005b65e0` + 16 (`0x00000001005b65f0`) and `bar` at + 24 (`0x00000001005b65f0`).

```
(lldb) memory read 0x00000001005b65e0
0x1005b65e0: a9 65 5b 00 01 80 1d 00 80 62 5b 00 03 00 00 00
0x1005b65f0: 70 e9 10 9e ff 7f 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

`foo` contains `0x0000007fff9e10e970` which in decimal is 140735845296496 and corresponds to:

```
(lldb) frame variable -L pointee
0x00000001005e2e18: (testmem.C) pointee = 0x00000001005b65e0 {
0x00000001005b65f0:   foo = 140735845296496 // this
0x00000001005b65f8:   bar = 0
}
```

And as this data wasn't allocated by my program we don't have access to it, hence the EXC_BAD_ACCESS error.

Life makes sense now .