# swift4: How to cast AnyObject to Pointer for C framework

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, pointers, frameworks

I'd like to work with a private macOS framework (MultitouchSupport.framework) in a swift project and got stuck at this point.

So far I get the address of the trackpad as AnyObject: `<MTDevice 0x10190b600 [0x7fff877ed5b0]>`. But the methods of this framework want that first hex value as a pointer `typedef void *MTDeviceRef;` argument.

The ObjC code that does what I need looks like this: `MTDeviceRef device = (__bridge MTDeviceRef)[deviceList objectAtIndex:i];`

I have tried converting via `as! MTDeviceRef` and `withUnsafePointer` with no luck.

Is there a way to convert this? I am still new to coding and swift, any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: This might be what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33310021/1187415.

Comment: Nice, this is the right direction. Now I get this error: Cannot convert value of type 'UnsafeRawPointer' to expected argument type 'MTDeviceRef!' (aka 'ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<UnsafeMutableRawPointer>')

Comment: Oh got that with a slight change. This did the trick: 
func bridge<T : AnyObject>(obj : T) -> UnsafeRawMutablePointer {
    return UnsafeRawMutablePointer(Unmanaged.passUnretained(obj).toOpaque())
}

Comment: Yes, my conversion functions assume *constant* pointers. I'll update the code for mutable pointers later.