# Cannot assign value of type 'UnsafeMutableRawPointer!' to type 'UIView'

Tags: ios, swift, unsafemutablepointer

I am trying to convert a Objective-C source code to Swift.

In Objective-C the below code

```
myView = (__bridge UIView *)([SmartPlayerSDK SmartPlayerCreatePlayView:0 y:0 width:screenWidth height:playerHeight]);
```

where `myView` is a `UIView`

I am using a library the function is given below,

```
+ (void*)SmartPlayerCreatePlayView:(NSInteger)x y:(NSInteger)y width:(NSInteger)width height:(NSInteger)height;
```

It return the address.

I am trying to convert to Swift

```
myView = SmartPlayerSDK.smartPlayerCreatePlayView(0, y: 0, width: 10, height: 10)

smartPlayerCreatePlayView - Automatically convert to small letter
```

got error: - `Cannot assign value of type 'UnsafeMutableRawPointer!' to type 'UIView'`

How to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bridging between raw pointers and managed object pointers is done
in Swift using the `Unmanaged` type. In your case the equivalent
code would be

```
let rawPointer = SmartPlayerSDK.smartPlayerCreatePlayView(0, y: 0, width: 10, height: 10)
let view = Unmanaged<UIView>.fromOpaque(rawPointer).takeUnretainedValue()
```

If `smartPlayerCreatePlayView()` returns a (+1) retained object
reference (as the "Create" in the method name indicates) then it
should be

```
let view = Unmanaged<UIView>.fromOpaque(rawPointer).takeRetainedValue()
```

to balance that, otherwise you have a memory leak.

For more bridging conversions, helper functions, and links
to the documentation, see [How to cast self to UnsafeMutablePointer<Void> type in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33294620/how-to-cast-self-to-unsafemutablepointervoid-type-in-swift).