# UnsafeMutableRawPointer load() is not returnning correct instance/value

Tags: swift

So I was learning and playing with the swift unsafe pointers.

```
let str0 = "hello world" as NSString
let ptr = Unmanaged.passUnretained(str0).toOpaque()

let s = ptr.load(as: NSString.self)
print(s)
ptr.deallocate()  // test purpose
```

the `s` is not "hello world", instead, it throws

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x1c)

If I change `NSString` to `CFString`, it won't crash, but the value of s is likely leaked:

```
(lldb) po s
2001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000

(lldb) p s
(NSDate) $R4 = 0x001dffff941aad41 2001-01-01 00:00:00 UTC
```

It's not the same type of CFString but NSDate, and it seems `s` is totally corrupted.

Can someone help explain what's going on? Where am I wrong about using load()? thanks!

Comment: `load()` is *not* the correct way to cast a raw pointer back to an object instance. Compare https://stackoverflow.com/a/33310021/1187415.

Comment: @MartinR then what's load() for? The document `Returns a new instance of the given type, constructed from the raw memory at the specified offset.` did seems implies me to do that way

Comment: `Unmanaged.passUnretained(str0).toOpaque()` is effectively just a pointer cast: A “managed pointer” is converted to an “unmanaged pointer” with the same value. The reverse conversion is `let str1 = Unmanaged<NSString>.fromOpaque(ptr).takeUnretainedValue()`. (More info in the answer that I referenced above.) – `load()` dereferences the pointer, i.e. loads data from the memory address that the pointer points to.

Comment: thanks for answering. however, I still wonder why my use is wrong? I didn't see any obvious that I shouldn't do it this way? Or how do I use reload() here?