# Is there a way to utilize Swift commands within a low-level C method call?

Tags: swift, unsafe-pointers, cvpixelbuffer, unsafemutablepointer

I am maintaining a set of data obtained from a `AVCaptureSynchronizedData`. One of the methods I use modifies the `CVPixelBuffers` obtained from the `AVCaptureSynchronizedData`. While modifying. the `CVPixelBuffer`, I create a copy of the `CVPixelBuffer` via

```
let status = CVPixelBufferCreateWithBytes(nil, scaleWidth, scaleHeight,
                                                  pixelFormat, destData,
                                                  destBytesPerRow, releaseCallback,
                                                  nil, nil, &dstPixelBuffer)
```

The `releaseCallBack` is referenced as

```
let releaseCallback: CVPixelBufferReleaseBytesCallback = { _, ptr in
    if let ptr = ptr {
        free(UnsafeMutableRawPointer(mutating: ptr))
    }
}
```

However, I would like to be able to keep up with how many times this is called. But, if I add something like

```
var num:Int = 0
let releaseCallback: CVPixelBufferReleaseBytesCallback = { _, ptr in
    if let ptr = ptr {
        num += 1
        free(UnsafeMutableRawPointer(mutating: ptr))
    }
}
```

I get the error

> A C function pointer cannot be formed from a closure that captures context

Not sure if it is possible, but it would be incredibly useful to be able to keep count of the number of times a pointer is destroyed

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33262376/1187415. – The problem is (as I assume) that `num` is an instance variable, so that the closure actually captures `self`.

Comment: Correct. It is implicitly self.num

Comment: Problem is, I cannot change the callback type as it is strictly a type created in Swift. It is looking for that specific callback. I believe the other solutions modifies it a little

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referencing the instance variable `num` in the closure captures `self` and that is not possible in the callback which is a pure C function.

Similarly as in [How to use instance method as callback for function which takes only func or literal closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33260808/how-to-use-instance-method-as-callback-for-function-which-takes-only-func-or-lit/33262376#33262376) you have to use that a custom pointer (here: `releaseRefCon`) can be passed to the callback:

```
let releaseCallback: CVPixelBufferReleaseBytesCallback = { releaseRefCon, ptr in
    let mySelf = Unmanaged<YourClass>.fromOpaque(releaseRefCon!).takeUnretainedValue()
    if let ptr = ptr {
        free(UnsafeMutableRawPointer(mutating: ptr))
        mySelf.num += 1
    }
}

let releaseRefCon = UnsafeMutableRawPointer(Unmanaged.passUnretained(self).toOpaque())
let status = CVPixelBufferCreateWithBytes(nil, scaleWidth, scaleHeight,
                                          pixelFormat, destData,
                                          destBytesPerRow,
                                          releaseCallback, releaseRefCon,
                                          nil, &dstPixelBuffer)
```

For the conversions from an instance pointer (here: `self`) to a void pointer and back to an instance pointer (here: `mySelf`) see [How to cast self to UnsafeMutablePointer<Void> type in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33294620/how-to-cast-self-to-unsafemutablepointervoid-type-in-swift).

Comment: Ahh I see. I saw the paramater releaseRefCon and I knew it was for instance variables but wasn’t sure on how yo create a UnsafeMutableRawPointer that allowed me to obtain a reference to self or anything else. Thanks so much!

Comment: I’ll test it out here shortly and give ya the check assuming all goes well