# How to mark the NSEvent as handled?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, cocoa

I handle pressing of letter keys on keyboard with the following code.

```
NSEvent.addGlobalMonitorForEvents(matching: NSEvent.EventTypeMask.keyDown) { event in
    // code
}
```

How do I then mark the NSEvent as handled, not allowing it to be handled again by system and another apps? For example do not allow the input of a pressed letter in the opened text editor?

Comment: Compare https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31891002/how-do-you-use-cgeventtapcreate-in-swift

Answer (score 5):

You can't do that with `NSEvent`. As the docs note:

> Events are delivered asynchronously to your app and you can only observe the event; you cannot modify or otherwise prevent the event from being delivered to its original target application.

You're not part of the event-generation system; you're just getting notifications as part of your runloop.

If you want to become part of the event system, below the app layer, you need to use `CGEvent`. See `tapCreate(tap:place:options:eventsOfInterest:callback:userInfo:)`. The callback can return `NULL` to indicate it's consumed the event.