# CGEvent.tapCreate returns nil even with sandbox disabled

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

I had a C file with a swift bridge that I could call for my macos program and it worked.

But it had a function CGEventTapCreate that only works in terminal by using sudo, otherwise it would return null, and that was the case.

So I ported the C code to Swift, but the function still returns nil because it don't have the privilege. The common solution is to disable sandbox, but the problem persists.

```
let eventTap : CFMachPort? =
    CGEvent.tapCreate ( tap: CGEventTapLocation.cgSessionEventTap
                      , place: .headInsertEventTap
                      , options: CGEventTapOptions.defaultTap
                      , eventsOfInterest: mask
                      , callback: myCGEventCallback
                      , userInfo: nil )

if eventTap == nil { -- always enter here
    print("[Swift] Failed to create event tap :(")
    exit(1)
}
```

TL;DR: how to give macOS apps permission to run CGEventTapCreate ?

Comment: Creating the event tap doesn't require any special permissions if you run outside of sandbox. Are you certain that your mask and callback are not causing problems?

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem and sandbox disabled.

I used "cgevent.tapcreate" to listen for keyboard events. Running in xode is fine, but my app won't work after I archive it.

Then I found the following words in apple's official documentation:
[doc link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgevent/1454426-tapcreate)

> Access for assistive devices is enabled. In OS X v10.4, you can enable this feature using System Preferences, Universal Access panel, Keyboard view.

You should apply for the access to the auxiliary function, code use swift 4:

```
func acquirePrivileges() {
    let trusted = kAXTrustedCheckOptionPrompt.takeUnretainedValue()
    let privOptions = [trusted: true] as CFDictionary
    let accessEnabled = AXIsProcessTrustedWithOptions(privOptions)

    if accessEnabled == true {

    } else {

    }
}
```

hope it helps