# Disable the builtin keyboard in mac os x programmatically?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, cocoa, keyboard

Is there a way to disable the keyboard in macos x?

I am looking for a way I can use this functinality in an application. So preferably something that can be done programatically and does not need root previlages?

I want the keyboard to be dsabled everywhere in the os, even if the application is in the background, until I enable it by pushing a butten for example.

I am new to mac os programming so will appreciate more elaborations :)

UPDATE: I am trying to use this: [CGEventTapCreate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31891002/how-do-you-use-cgeventtapcreate-in-swift/53402899#53402899) but cannot get it to work. Anyone nows how to make it work in swift 3?

Answer (score 0):

You can override the keyDown and keyUp events and leave the function without calling its super class

```
override func keyDown(with event: NSEvent) {
    //super.keyDown(event)
}
override func keyUp(with event: NSEvent) {
    //super.keyUp(event)
}
```

The above code works for NSTextView

For NSTextField, you should manually delete the letter entered. As for NSTextfield's keyDown event will not be called when overrided.

```
override func keyUp(with event: NSEvent) {
    self.stringValue = ""
}
```

I used these techniques, but not really sure if this is right way to do... But it works :P

Comment: Thank for the responce, but let make myself clear. I want to completely disabe the keyboard, any input, anywhere, not just in the app.

Comment: This would not work. I want to disable/enable keyboard based on clickong a button. Thanks though.